# Context-menu in Adobe Flash application is not showing in Windows 10 with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: windows, flash, internet-explorer, adobe, contextmenu

We're in the process of upgrading all company PC's to Windows 10. We noticed that a critical internal legacy flash application which is used by 350+ users is not able to show any kind of context menu within Internet Explorer 11 when run on Windows 10. With IE 11 run on Windows 7 the flash application can show the context menu - simply by issuing a right click - as expected.

I've conducted some tests:

- Win 7 + Chrome (Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)) + Flash (22,0,0,209 bundled) >> Context-menu NOT WORKING
- Win 10 + Chrome (Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)) + Flash (22,0,0,209 bundled) >> Context-menu NOT WORKING
- Win 7 + IE 11 (Version 11.0.9600.18376) + Flash (22,0,0,210 installed)   >> Context-menu WORKS
- Win 10 + IE 11 (Version 11.494.10586.0) + Flash (22,0,0,209 installed)   >> Context-menu NOT WORKING (main problem)
- Win 7 + Firefox (Version 48.0) + Flash (22,0,0,209 installed)    >> Context-menu WORKS
- Win 10 + Firefox (Version 48.0) + Flash (22,0,0,209 installed)   >> Context-menu WORKS

I am not able upgrading the flash version on Windows 10 since 22,0,0,209 is the newest version offered by windows update.

Did anyone run into this and found a solution? Maybe some registry setting? Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: The HTML file which is embedding the flash SWF file also referenced a script called "RightClick.js" (https://code.google.com/archive/p/custom-context-menu/). I believe it was necessary in the distant past if you wanted to create a custom context menu for a flash app.

I just removed the include from the HTML file and the context menu now works in all browsers listed above.

Just wanted to let stackoverflow know since I have not found a solution somewhere else on the internet ;)